# Error while trying to Use ShareXFiles method from share_plus package

Tags: flutter, dart

Since the method: shareFiles has been deprecated, now I need to change it to shareXFiles but for some reason It's giving me the :

> Share callback error, prior share-sheet did not call back, did you
> await it?

Here's my code:

```
      _invoiceService.extractPDFromURL(url, uiid).then((file) async {
        XFile xfile = XFile(file.path); //at this part, my file is perfect (at least it works if I change the ShareXFiles to ShareFile method...)
        await Share.shareXFiles([xfile], text: 'PDF Document');
        LoadingService.hide();
      }).catchError((e) {
        LoadingService.hide();
        ToastService.error(e.toString());
      });
```

ExtractPDFromURL method:

```
Future<File> extractPDFromURL(String url, String uuid) async {
    try {
      Uint8List bytes = await _invoiceRepository.downloadPdfFileFromURL(url);

      return getFile(uuid, bytes);
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }


Future<File> getFile(String invoiceId, Uint8List bytes) async {
    final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final file = File('${output.path}/invoice_$invoiceId.pdf');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
    return file;
  }
```